# Rejecting values in multivariable equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

Say we have a system of equations involving more than one variable, for eg:
$${x}^2 - {y}^2 = 48$$
$$x - y = 8$$
This can be solved as follows:
$$(x-y)(x+y) = 48$$
Since $x-y=8$ , the equation becomes
$$8(x+y)=48$$
$$x+y=6$$
Adding ($x-y=8$) and ($x+y=6$) to get
$$2x = 14$$
$$x=7$$

Till here, there is no problem. But when we put the value of $x=7$ in the very first equation we get two values for y(+1 and -1).
But only one of them i.e., $y=-1$ is consistent with both the equations. The other value of y gets rejected. So my question is:

**Why do we get two values of $y$ if only one of them is consistent?**

*I know it's absurd, but this question has been gnawing at my brain for a week and I haven't been able to come up with a decent answer.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Knowing $x$ leaves us with a quadratic equation having two solutions. But knowing $x-y$ here gives us also $x+y$ , enough to uniquely determine $x$ and $y$. What you have done is to "forget" this useful information ($x-y=8$) allowing no longer to uniquely determine the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While solving, you have reason by equivalences, hence always maintain 2 equations. Your initial system implies what you wrote after, but is not equivalent. Written rigorously, your argument leads to the (unique) solution :
$$[(x-y)(x+y)=48\text{ and }x-y=8]$$
$$\Leftrightarrow[8(x+y)=48\text{ and }x-y=8]$$
$$\Leftrightarrow[x+y=6\text{ and }x-y=8]$$
$$\Leftrightarrow[x=7\text{ and }x-y=8]$$
$$\Leftrightarrow[x=7\text{ and }y=-1].$$

Answer (score 2):

It is a general fact when you solve equations by implications. If
\begin{equation}
\text{System A}\Longrightarrow\text{System B}
\end{equation}
then it means that System B has more solutions than System A, that is to say every solution of System A is a solution of System B but the converse is not necessarily true.

In your case, System B is $\left\{\begin{align}y^2=1\cr x=7\end{align}\right.$.

Of course if you replace $x$ by $7$ in the second equation ($x-y=8$), you obtain directly that $y=-1$.

To elaborate a little more on this matter, note that if $\text{System A}\Longrightarrow\text{System B}$, then
\begin{equation}
\text{System A}\Longleftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}[l]\cr
\text{System A}\cr
\text{System B}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
So in your case, this entails
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}[l]\cr
x^2-y^2=48\cr
x - y = 8
\end{array}\right.
\Longleftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}[l]\cr
x^2-y^2=48\cr
x-y=8\cr
x=7
\end{array}\right.
\Longleftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}[l]\cr
y^2=1\cr
y=-1\cr
x=7
\end{array}\right.
\Longleftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}[l]\cr
y=-1\cr
x=7
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

Comment: I agree that downvotes must be left with a comment atleast. I've seen one each on many of my recent questions/answers without any comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1:**

For a given value of $x$ the quadratic equation will return 2 roots while the linear equation will return 1 root. So, while the linear equation will give me the correct value of $y$ that satisfies both, the quadratic equation will give me 2 values instead and while one is a crew-mate other must be the imposter. 
So, instead put $x=7$ in the equations of the line to get the required value.

An interesting analogy is that suppose A who is an engineer is finding his partner who is also an engineer to work on a project. A's partner lives in a rented shared room. So, when A is standing out his partner's room and calls for him, 2 people come out as both of their names are B, one is engineer and the other a doctor. A recognizes his partner and goes on to work with him.

**Way 2:**

[image: pic]

As you can see from the above pic, there are 3 things in play. Once you have found out that $x=7$, now you must find the common point between the 3 equations.